# Case conversion in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for functionality in python equivalent to case in SQL. Basically I have category data in my Dataframe, I want to convert something like below.

```
Case when Column='X' then 'A' when Column='Y' then 'B' End.
```

Is there any equivalent functionality in Python?

Comment: Do you mean that you're looking for functionality in Pandas?

Comment: Use `dictionary` for mapping and replace it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas built-in function 'replace', providing a dictionary where key is the label to replace, and value is the label to replace with:

```
df =pd.DataFrame({'Data': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
                  'Labels': ['X', 'Y', 'Y', 'X', 'Y']})
df['Labels'] = df['Labels'].replace({'X': 'A', 'Y': 'B'})
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

EDIT:

For more detailed replacement, if you know the exact string you want to replace you can just write as above e.g. {'BHK Apartment': Apartment'}. Otherwise if you want to replace any string that contains a substring e.g.'Villa' you can use regexp:

```
df =pd.DataFrame({'Data': [4, 4, 2],
                  'Labels': ['BHK Apartment', 'BHK Villa', 'BHK PentHouse']})
df['Labels'] = df['Labels'].replace({r'.*Apartment$': 'Apartment', r'.*Villa$': 'Villa', r'.*PentHouse$': 'PentHouse'}, regex=True)
```

https://kanoki.org/2019/11/12/how-to-use-regex-in-pandas/

Comment: Instead apple to apple comparison, can i replace matching character set with another string? For example, source data is {4+ BHK Apartment, 4+ BHK Villa, 2 BHK PentHouse} and the target data i wanted is {Apartment, Villa, PentHouse}. There are many different types of houses, i wanted to categorize them like {Apartment, Villa, PentHouse, StudioApartment}.